# When did vinyl switch from “Side One/Two” to “A/B Side”?

Tags: recording, vinyl, record-labels, record, vinyl-pressing

Not sure if this is universal but I’ve been going through some of my dad’s records (late ‘60s to ‘80s) and I’ve noticed that all of his vinyls describe the first side as “Side One” and the back side as “Side Two”, where my vinyls (mid 2000s-today) equivalently describe the respective sides as “A side” and “B side”.

Does anyone know when this changed, and why?

I know that some even older records used to go by “A/B side” to delineate between the more popular songs [as mentioned in this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-side_and_B-side), so maybe the naming has shuffled around a few times?

For reference, a lot of the record companies from my dad’s archive were Columbia, Warner Bros, Capitol, and Apple Records. Many of mine are Domino, Sub Pop, Warp, Carpark. Not sure if it’s as simple as record label specific, but even then, when/why did labels switch naming conventions?

Answer (score -1):

This was something that was standardised within the individual record company for years.  Slowly people worked out that a record didn't have to conform to Side 1/2 or A/B and started playing with it.  As far as I know, Elvis was the first not to have his name on the cover of the album.  The first custom label I recall seeing was the Beatles *Let It Be* with the red apple.  The first that I can recall where they actually played with the naming of the sides was The Firesign Theatre *Don't Crush That Dwarf, Hand Me the Pliers* which had This Side/The Other Side, but was otherwise one track over the entire album in 1970, although that one did have 1/2 also on the label.  It was a big thing when indie was new, e.g. Minutemen *Double Nickels on the Dime* which had Side D./Mike/George/Chaff.  The Residents *George & James* didn't specify because they didn't want you to pick one over the other as the first side.

I first started seeing A/B or A/AA etc. on dance records starting in the rave era.  Sometimes you need it in that world to refer to tracks that don't have titles, e.g. Slipmatt's "SMD#1A" and "SMD#1AA" (the record itself just says SMD on the label with no titles or mention of Slipmatt, and no label for the B-side), or the entire Naughty Naughty series from Grant Nelson.  One of my favourite records from the era is EOAD "Love the Feeling" -- the A side has the title, but the two tracks on the flip are both called Remix on the label, so they became "Love The Feeling A1", "Love the Feeling B1", "Love the Feeling B2".  You can see this sometimes on dance compilations and sometimes they credit the wrong track and project name.  Frequently the label wouldn't have anything on it at all, and some of those are still mysteries as to who is behind them.